# Web api project routing trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have simple web API project (ASP.NET MVC). I need to deploy my project in the subfolder on the IIS. For example, I have the site `http://TestSite`/ and I need to deploy the project to `http://TestSite/MyProject/`. When I did it, web API routing stopped to work. Because my ajax call is routed to the main site - `http://TestSite/api/something/get`.

I have tried to update map routing in the next way:

```
routeTemplate: "MyProject/api/{controller}/{id}",
```

But it doesn't affect as I want. What I am doing wrong and where can I read about some practices of web API control routing in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Do you have a web.config in your subfolder to overwrite the default web.config? You might also need to wrap your default web config's <system.web> and <system.webserver> sections with <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">

Comment: Yes, I have. Thank for note about "local" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty simple. I didn't need to do anything with routing. I just needed to change url in JavaScript.

From:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Category', function (data) {
```

To:

```
$.getJSON('api/Category', function (data) {
```

Just remove '/' symbol before 'api'. Be aware.

BTW, nice article about debugging ASP.NET Web API - [Debugging ASP.NET Web API with Route Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx)

**EDIT:** Forget that I wrote before (instead of the BTW section). This doesn't work. It works for `http://TestSite/MyProject/` but doesn't work for `http://TestSite/MyProject/MyController/Index`. I met such kind of issue with my past ASP.NET MVC project. And I solved it by starting to use [Url helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) e.g: `@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")`. So I needed something like for Web Api. And I found it. It is [UrlHelper.HttpRouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128146%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method. Now my code looks in the next way:

```
$.getJSON( "@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi",new {controller = "Category"})", function (data) {
```

Where:

- DefaultApi - name of my default rote.
- Category - name of my api controller.

This solution doesn't look elegant but it works.